# wordpress use video instead of image

Tags: wordpress

I need to use a video instead of an image exactly at a specific locations in a wordpress theme. I've seen several tutorials but they're not solving the problem.

I've tried plugins but they're only usable for a fresh page.

Comment: Have you looked in to Advanced Custom Fields? It allows you to add custom fields to any content type and then output them in your template wherever you want. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: use meta mox for video selection and retrieve that data from theme. you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-metabox/ for the meta box also ( i never use it) hope it helps.